# UNION with WHERE clause - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm creating a search interface using UNION for searching multiple tables. My problem is, the data in the last table is the only thing that keeps appearing when I try to search for the word. How can I search the tables properly where the condition is, the name should be searched according to its first letter.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (searchText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_acc  WHERE name LIKE ?" +
                        " UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_filems  WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_psu  WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_shells  WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_sic  WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id,name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_stp WHERE name LIKE ?", 
                        new String[]{searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), 
                R.layout.search_command_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"name", "desc"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.commandName, R.id.commandDesc}, 0);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else {

                }

        }



    });

}
```

Comment: You have 6 parameters in SQL query, but you are supplying only one in the argument array.

Comment: So how can I fix it? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unused parameters get a value of NULL; only the `comm_acc` table is actually searched.

You have to give six parameters to the query:

```
String searchPattern = searchText.getText().toString() + "%";
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ... ? ... ? ... ? ... ? ... ? ... ? ...",
                     new String[]{ searchPattern, searchPattern, searchPattern,
                                   searchPattern, searchPattern, searchPattern });
```

or use the same parameter in all LIKEs:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("          SELECT ... name LIKE ?1 " +
                     "UNION ALL SELECT ... name LIKE ?1 " +
                     ...
                     "UNION ALL SELECT ... name LIKE ?1",
                     new String[]{ searchText.getText().toString() + "%" });
```

Comment: Can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263130/retrieve-information-using-union-android-eclipse?noredirect=1#

Comment: @user3398666 How is that not a duplicate?

Comment: This code is for searching multiple tables. And that link is for retrieving the information when the search item is clicked.